# Non volatile head and tail reference in Java LinkedBlockingQueue

Tags: java, concurrency

Why does `java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue` have a `head` and `tail` reference as non `volatile`?

Any change in `head` or `tail` in one thread may not be visible to another thread, so will this lead to issues?

Comment: Interesting question. Especially when one starts reading the source code of that class and finds that it contains quite some commented-out stuff about locking; and locking methods ... that aren't used?!

Comment: It uses a locks to provide thread safety.

Comment: From the source code, I see the head and tail as "transient", which is different than "non-volatile".

Comment: `transient` and `volatile` aren't related. `transient` is for serialization.

Comment: @JohnVint Yup, though they mean the same thing (both words are synonyms, meaning "lasting only a short time"), they are not related in any way.

Answer (score 8):

The `head` and `tail` are going to be guarded by the `putLock` or `takeLock`. As long as your synchronize appropriately, you don't need to declare the fields as `volatile`.

So, to answer your question. The fields don't need to be `volatile` if they are correctly synchronized (which they are).

If there is a part of the code you find suspect, let me know, otherwise I cannot find any reason they need to be volatile.

Comment: You mean ReentrantLock gurantees all subsequent read and write will happen to main memory not cache  as in synchronized block so another Thread calling take method will always read the head from main memory.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. From the JDK `All Lock implementations must enforce the same memory synchronization semantics as provided by the built-in monitor lock, as described in section 17.4 of The Java™ Language Specification`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no, it won't cause visibility issues.

Long answer: it's blocking, i.e. it has some sort of `synchronized {}` blocks at the hear of the implementation. You can propagate variable changes through `synchronized {}` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

> java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue have a head and tail
>   reference as non volatile

First of all, `volatile` is a synchronization technique but not the only technique - other synchronization technique being explicit locking so `volatile` is not always mandatory provided field synchronization is handled by locking. So as explained in John Vint's answer, those two locks are used here.

Secondly, you wouldn't usually see `volatile` being used for reference types. Its generally used for primitive types, see this [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075517/do-i-need-volatile-for-variables-of-reference-types-too) for additional explanations - both answers are great there.

Also  [refer this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371066/volatile-for-reference-type-does-it-always-avoid-publication-of-references-iss) to see that just declaring a reference type to be `volatile` is sometimes not enough and can still produce incorrect results since what usually matters for reference type are non stale values of fields of reference type and not actual reference itself.  A non - stale reference correctly visible to all threads might have stale field values for underlying object in different threads.